# Can't find globally installed npm packages in Travis ci

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, continuous-integration, travis-ci

The `.travis.yml` file is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
env:
  global:
    - secure: "[redacted]"
before_install:
- node ./bin/version_check.js
install:
- npm i
- npm i -g codecov
- npm i -g @octokit/rest
script:
- npm run lint
- npm run build
- npm run ci
deploy:
- skip_cleanup: true
  provider: npm
  email: obfishstudio@gmail.com
  api_key:
    secure: "[redacted]"
  on:
    repo: jjyyxx/JSONSchemaSimulator
    branch: master
- skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: node ./bin/auto_release.js
  on:
    repo: jjyyxx/JSONSchemaSimulator
    branch: master
```

On the install stage, `@octokit/rest` package is installed. But in the second deploy task, when I required it in the first line of `./bin/auto_release.js`:

```
const Octokit = require('@octokit/rest')
```

Travis CI showed that `Error: Cannot find module '@octokit/rest'`.

The project is available at https://github.com/jjyyxx/JSONSchemaSimulator.

The ci report is available at https://travis-ci.org/jjyyxx/JSONSchemaSimulator/builds/408414549.

Comment: I would highly recommend censoring the secure API keys!

Comment: In the item `secure: xxx`, `xxx` actually is encrypted with a public key, whose corresponding private key is only known by the Travis ci backend, so it's safe to open source that. But thanks for your reminder anyway!

Comment: As I said, haven't worked with Travis CI yet, and if I spot something along the lines of `api_key` followed by `secure`, it's always better to be a bit too cautions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I haven't worked with Travis CI before, but I'm using GitLab CI and actually had the same situation.

The problem is, that the global packages will not be incorporated into the cache for the jobs, and therefore will be removed after `install` has finished.

For this kind of setup, I highly recommend installing the packages locally, not globally.

One of the reasons for this is that an executor might be used for different build jobs, where it would be very unfortunate if different package versions are installed globally and interfere with each other.

Comment: That made prefect sense! Thank you for your accurate solution. Just changing `npm i -g @octokit/rest` to `npm i @octokit/rest` solves the problem.